# MYSQL GroupBy with Join: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables. Invoices table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` date NOT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And invoice services:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_services` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to see profits by each month for each year:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(i.created_date,'%Y-%m') as month, sum(profit) as profit
FROM invoices as i
JOIN (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(value) as profit FROM invoice_services isrv) isrv
ON i.id = isrv.invoice_id
GROUP BY month
```

But I get the error:

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'isrv.invoice_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I want to keep this sql mode and I just cannot wrap my head around it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 'I want to keep this sql mode' not with you did you mean the opposite?

Comment: with this sql mode (as the error is telling you) you need to include all the non-aggregate select items int the group by clause

Comment: Since `i.id = isrv.invoice_id`, why do you need to select both of them?

Comment: You're grouping by month, and there will be lots of different invoices in the same month. Which invoice ID should it show?

Comment: I only need them to make the join, don't want to have them in the result.

Comment: Then take them out of the `SELECT` list. It should just be `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(...) as month, SUM(profit) AS profit`

Comment: I actually don't need any id of invoice, just want to have the profit by month.

Comment: Removed the ids from SELECT, getting the same error though. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the invoice IDs in the result, so take them out of the `SELECT` list.

You need to add `GROUP BY` to the subquery.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(i.created_date,'%Y-%m') as month, sum(profit) as profit
FROM invoices as i
JOIN (
    SELECT invoice_id, SUM(value) as profit 
    FROM invoice_services
    GROUP BY invoice_id) isrv
ON i.id = isrv.invoice_id
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: This still gives me the error: `#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'isrv.invoice_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: You were missing `GROUP BY` in the subquery.